# `#[derive(Clone)]` seems to wrongfully enforce generic to be `Clone`

Tags: generics, rust

It seems that when deriving `Clone`, Rust forwards the `Clone` trait requirement to Generics that do not require the trait, like if they are wrapped inside an `Arc`.

Do I misunderstand how `Clone` works or is this a compiler mistake?

Consider the following code, where `a.clone()` works, but `b.clone()` does not.
Also note that without the `b.clone()` call, the code compiles fine, indicating that `#[derive(Clone)]` worked.

```rust
use std::sync::Arc;

struct Unclonable {}

struct A<T>(Arc<T>);
impl<T> Clone for A<T> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        Self(self.0.clone())
    }
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct B<T>(Arc<T>);

fn main() {
    let a = A(Arc::new(Unclonable {}));
    let b = B(Arc::new(Unclonable {}));

    // Works
    a.clone();
    // Fails
    b.clone();
}
```

```
   |
3  | struct Unclonable {}
   | ----------------- doesn't satisfy `Unclonable: Clone`
...
13 | struct B<T>(Arc<T>);
   | --------------------
   | |
   | method `clone` not found for this
   | doesn't satisfy `B<Unclonable>: Clone`
...
22 |     b.clone();
   |       ^^^^^ method cannot be called on `B<Unclonable>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
   |
   = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `Unclonable: Clone`
           which is required by `B<Unclonable>: Clone`
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
   = note: the following trait defines an item `clone`, perhaps you need to implement it:
           candidate #1: `Clone`
help: consider annotating `Unclonable` with `#[derive(Clone)]`
   |
3  | #[derive(Clone)]
   |
```

When I [expand](https://github.com/dtolnay/cargo-expand) the macros, I see the following generated code:

```
#![feature(prelude_import)]
#[prelude_import]
use std::prelude::rust_2018::*;
#[macro_use]
extern crate std;
use std::sync::Arc;
struct Unclonable {}
struct A<T>(Arc<T>);
impl<T> Clone for A<T> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        Self(self.0.clone())
    }
}
struct B<T>(Arc<T>);
#[automatically_derived]
#[allow(unused_qualifications)]
impl<T: ::core::clone::Clone> ::core::clone::Clone for B<T> {
    #[inline]
    fn clone(&self) -> B<T> {
        match *self {
            B(ref __self_0_0) => B(::core::clone::Clone::clone(&(*__self_0_0))),
        }
    }
}
fn main() {
    let a = A(Arc::new(Unclonable {}));
    let b = B(Arc::new(Unclonable {}));
    a.clone();
    b.clone();
}
```

What is going on?
Why would the Rust compiler add `<T: ::core::clone::Clone>`??

Or is this just one of those cases where the intended way is to implement `Clone` manually?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not a compiler bug, in the sense that it's a [documented behavior](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes/derive.html), even though one might find it weird. The compiler will automatically add constraints to generic types when deriving, even if those constraints are not actually required in the implementation. For instance, deriving `Clone` for `B<T>` will only implement `Clone for B<T>` where `T: Clone`, even though it would be possibly to implement that regardless of whether `T` is `Clone`.

So, for the time being (maybe the compiler will get smarter about these cases in the future), yes, it's one of those cases where you have to implement manually.

Comment: I'm not actually sures that the current behavior follows from that documentation. It does say that `T: Clone` will be used, but only in the context of an example where `T` is used in the field. If the field used, say, `Rc<T>`, one could expect the constraint to be `Rc<T>: Clone`, rather than `T: Clone` - and yet it's still `T: Clone` for [complicated reasons](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/26925).

Comment: @user4815162342 well, as I see it, it's just a bug: the documented behavior is logically wrong, but the implementation follows the documented behavior. The reason behind this behavior is that it's hard to reason about bounds when derives are expanded I think. Btw, simply adding the constraint `Rc<T>: Clone`, as in your example, will not work in general, because `Rc` might be private.

Comment: I'm not sure where you see the current behavior documented. The documentation you linked only refers to the example where the current behavior does make sense.

Comment: @user4815162342 hum... indeed I re-read the reference and it doesn't document much. Either it has changed since when I posted it, or I saw it documented somewhere else (maybe in an issue or alike), or maybe I just imagined it :/

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind a small dependency, you can avoid the drudgery<sup>1</sup> of manual implementation using the `derivative` crate:

```
#[derive(Derivative)]
#[derivative(Clone(bound = ""))]
struct B<T>(Arc<T>);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2cafd62f195c0aefb19ba4b011b77e2a)

<sup>1</sup> In the case of a small struct the drudgery is not that bad, but in case of an `enum` with many variants, the implementation gets quite large.