# Why does MyEnum<T> requires T to implement the Clone trait to derive the Clone trait when T is never cloned?

Tags: rust, tree, clone, traits

See the following tree data structure where `T` is behind an `Rc` which does not clone `T` when it is cloned itself.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub enum Tree<T> where T {
    Leaf { value: Rc<T> },
    Tree { children: Vec<Tree<T>> },
}
```

But now the compiler tells me:

```
note: trait bound `T: Clone` was not satisfied
   |
   | #[derive(Debug, Clone)]
   |                 ^^^^^ unsatisfied trait bound introduced in this `derive` macro
   = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `T: Clone`
           which is required by `Tree<T>: Clone`
help: consider restricting the type parameter to satisfy the trait bound
   |
   | pub enum Tree<T> where T: Clone {
   |                        ++++++++
```

Since `Rc<T>` does not actually clone T, I expected T is not required to implement `Clone`.

Comment: Likely a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72150623/1600898), but there might be better precedents.

Comment: Note that this is a limitation only on *deriving* `Clone`, i.e. letting the compiler implement it automatically. You can still easily *implement* `Clone` yourself, just by doing it manually: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=806ac1170392030d1cd7c7b03cc2c0ae.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes you are right, the mentioned question answers this.

Comment: Also, if you don't mind a small dependency, you can avoid the drudgery of manual implementation with the derivative crate: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cf1bea0e505eadfb95dfb6b03e96e0a9